# PG-Promise - transaction logic for two databases

Tags: pg-promise

How can I distribute transactions between two different DBs with PG-Promise? Commits or rollbacks should be applied to both DBs and if one fails, the other should revert changes

I have been using something like this but I am not sure if it works:

```js
try {
    await firstDb.tx(async (firstDbTask) => {
      await secondDb.tx(async (secondDbTask) => {
        // second db stuff
      })
      // first db stuff
    });

    return true;
} catch (err) {    
    return err;
}
```

Comment: You are mixing two unrelated subjects here into one question. One is about distributed transactions, across databases, and the other about transactions chaining with `pg-promise`. These two things are unrelated. You need to understand better what it is doing first, and then ask a better question.

Comment: I was wondering about distributed transactions between multiple DBs. Edited question and title

Comment: Note that I thoroughly revamped my answer after you accepted it. There were some problems with the initial answer. Now it looks much better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronizing transaction logic for multiple databases isn't trivial, but doable. And the solution is basically all about correct use of promises, not much else...

We make our multi-database transactions expose their final inner state via an external promise, so we can cross-align transaction outcome to that state:

```js
let firstTx, secondTx;

firstTx = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firstDb.tx(async t => {
        // do your queries here first...

        // success, signal after all the queries:
        resolve(/*null or whatever data*/);

        // Align COMMIT-ROLLBACK logic with the other transaction:
        await secondTx;
    }).catch(reject);
});

secondTx = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    secondDb.tx(async t => {
        // do your queries here first...

        // success, signal at the end:
        resolve(/*null or whatever data*/);

        // Align COMMIT-ROLLBACK logic with the other transaction:
        await firstTx;
    }).catch(reject);
});

await Promise.all([firstTx, secondTx]); // finish transactions logic
```

This approach ensures that if either of the transactions fails, both will roll back. And `COMMIT` can only happen either for both transactions or none.

---

Note however, that the solution above is a little loose in relation to the state of the transactions, i.e. after we call `Promise.all` there, both transactions have finished executing their logic, but the resulting `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` haven't finished executing yet.

In case you need full closure on both transactions, you have to follow up with a separate `await` for the actual transactions to end, as shown below:

```js
let firstTx, secondTx, tx1, tx2;

firstTx = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tx1 = firstDb.tx(async t => {
        // do your queries here first...

        // success, signal after all the queries:
        resolve(/*null or whatever data*/);

        // Align COMMIT-ROLLBACK logic with the other transaction:
        await secondTx;
    }).catch(reject);
});

secondTx = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tx2 = secondDb.tx(async t => {
        // do your queries here first...

        // success, signal at the end:
        resolve(/*null or whatever data*/);

        // Align COMMIT-ROLLBACK logic with the other transaction:
        await firstTx;
    }).catch(reject);
});

await Promise.all([firstTx, secondTx]); // finish transactions logic

await Promise.all([tx1, tx2]); // finish transactions execution

// All COMMIT-s or ROLLBACK-s have been executed.
```

Note that the above provision only matters when both transactions succeed with a `COMMIT`. When either one fails, the first `await` will throw, so the second one won't execute, which is important because in case of failure, `tx1` or `tx2` may still be `undefined`. That's why we have two separate `await`-s there in the end.

Comment: This is great, thank you. It looks very promising (heh) for my case